# Upload to test.pypi.org fails with "503: Service Unavailable"

Tags: python, pypi, twine

When I try to upload a wheel to test.pypi.org, it fails with "503: Service Unavailable".  This is the command that I am trying to run:

```
python -m twine upload --verbose --repository test open_source_risk_engine-1.8.11.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl
```

Below is the output.  It gives me a link to twitter.com but that web site does not exist.  It also refers me to https://status.python.org but that page indicates that all services are running.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
INFO     Using configuration from C:\Users\username\.pypirc
Uploading distributions to https://test.pypi.org/legacy/
INFO     open_source_risk_engine-1.8.11.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (20.8 MB)
INFO     username set from config file
INFO     password set from config file
INFO     username: __token__
INFO     password: <hidden>
Uploading open_source_risk_engine-1.8.11.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl
100% ---------------------------------------- 21.8/21.8 MB • 00:17 • 1.4 MB/s
WARNING  Received "503: Service Unavailable"
         Package upload appears to have failed. Retry 1 of 5.
Uploading open_source_risk_engine-1.8.11.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl
100% ---------------------------------------- 21.8/21.8 MB • 00:17 • 1.4 MB/s
WARNING  Received "503: Service Unavailable"
         Package upload appears to have failed. Retry 2 of 5.
Uploading open_source_risk_engine-1.8.11.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl
100% ---------------------------------------- 21.8/21.8 MB • 00:17 • 1.4 MB/s
WARNING  Received "503: Service Unavailable"
         Package upload appears to have failed. Retry 3 of 5.
Uploading open_source_risk_engine-1.8.11.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl
100% ---------------------------------------- 21.8/21.8 MB • 00:17 • 1.4 MB/s
WARNING  Received "503: Service Unavailable"
         Package upload appears to have failed. Retry 4 of 5.
Uploading open_source_risk_engine-1.8.11.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl
100% ---------------------------------------- 21.8/21.8 MB • 00:17 • 1.4 MB/s
WARNING  Received "503: Service Unavailable"
         Package upload appears to have failed. Retry 5 of 5.
INFO     Response from https://test.pypi.org/legacy/:
         503 Service Unavailable
INFO     <!DOCTYPE html>
         <html lang="en">
           <head>
             <meta charset="utf-8">
             <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
             <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

             <meta name="defaultLanguage" content="en">
             <meta name="availableLanguages" content="en">

             <title>Service Unavailable (503)</title>

             <meta name="description" content="The Python Package Index (PyPI) is a repository of software for the
         Python programming language.">

             <!-- Fonts -->
             <link rel="stylesheet"
         href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic|Source
         +Code+Pro:500">

             <style>
               html,
               body {
                 box-sizing: border-box;
                 font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', 'Helvetica', Arial, sans-serif;
                 font-size: 17px;
                 line-height: 1.4;
                 font-weight: 300;
                 color: #fff;
                 -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
                 font-size: 100%;
                 padding: 0;
                 margin: 0;
               }

               h1, strong {
                 font-weight: 600;
               }

               ul {
                 list-style-type: none;
                 padding-left: 0;
               }

               hr {
                 margin: 50px auto;
                 width: 300px;
                 max-width: 100%;
                 border: 0;
                 height: 2px;
                 background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
               }

               .viewport-section {
                 height: 100vh;
                 display: flex;
                 align-items: center;
                 justify-content: center;
                 background-color: #006dad;
                 color: #fff;
               }

               .viewport-section a {
                 color: #fff;
               }

               .viewport-section__content {
                 text-align: center;
                 padding: 30px;
                 min-width: 0;
               }

               .viewport-section__heading {
                 font-size: 2.4em;
                 padding: 20px 15px 0;
                 margin: 0;
               }

               @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
                 .viewport-section__content {
                   padding: 15px;
                 }

                 .viewport-section__heading {
                   font-size: 1.5em;
                 }
               }
             </style>

           </head>

           <body>
             <div class="viewport-section">
               <div class="viewport-section__content">
                 <img alt="PyPI logo"
         src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSI2NS44MTIiIGhlaWd
         odD0iNTgiIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCA2NS44MTIwMzUgNTguMDAwMDAxIj48ZyBmaWxsPSIjYTI5ZDg2IiBzdHJva2U9IiNjY2MiIHN0cm9rZS13a
         WR0aD0iLjIxNCIgc3Ryb2tlLWxpbmVqb2luPSJiZXZlbCI+PHBhdGggZD0iTTE4LjkzIDE4LjgyNmw5LjMyMyAzLjM5NHYxMC45NTdsLTkuMzI
         wNC01LjIwNnoiIGZpbGw9IiMyZjY0OTEiLz48cGF0aCBkPSJNMjY0MC43NzIgODAzLjM3NHYxNi44MTFsMTQuNTE1LTUuMjgzdi0xNi44MTF6I
         iBmaWxsPSIjMzc3NWE5Ii8+PHBhdGggZD0iTTI2MjYuNDY4IDc5OC4xNjhsMTQuMzA0IDUuMjA2djE2LjgxMWwtMTQuMzA0LTUuMjA2eiIgZml
         sbD0iIzJmNjQ5MSIvPjwvZz48Y2lyY2xlIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0ic2tld1koLTIwKSBzY2FsZSguOTM5NyAxKSIgY3k9IjE3NzIuOTIyIiBjeD0iM
         jgxNi4wMTciIHI9IjIuOTY3IiBmaWxsPSIjZmZmIi8+PC9nPjwvc3ZnPg==">
                 <h1 class="viewport-section__heading">Sorry, something went wrong</h1>

                 <div class="viewport-section__text">
                   <p>PyPI is down for maintenance or is having an outage.</p>
                   <p>
                     This is affecting several of our services, including our web interface.</br>
                     If you are trying to install a package, you should be able to <strong>pip install</strong>
         packages without problem.
                   </p>

                   <ul class="unstyled">
                     <li><a href="https://status.python.org/">Check our status page</a>, or</li>
                     <li><a href="https://twitter.com/PythonStatus">View Python Status on Twitter</a></li>
                   </ul>

                   <hr>

                   <p>
                     <strong>
                       Rely on PyPI to get your job done?</br>
                       Consider <a href="https://github.com/pypa/warehouse">contributing</a> or <a
         href="https://psfmember.org/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=13">donating</a> to help us build a more
         stable and secure platform.
                     </strong>
                   </p>
                 </div>
               </div>
             </div>
           </body>
         </html>

ERROR    HTTPError: 503 Service Unavailable from https://test.pypi.org/legacy/
         Service Unavailable
```

Comment: According to that link, the only thing "down" is that "Fastly Europe (LCY)" is "Under maintenance", which is the London City region; maybe you just coincidentally are in an affected area?

Comment: Oh, that might be it.  I will try again after that service comes back up and report back.  Thank you!